# How to use Google Search query in PHP?

Tags: php, google-search, google-search-api

I am trying to use Google Search query in my website, I need to get website URLs for the text I sent to the query, the code works fine for limited results, but then it stops working after some time, maybe Google disables it for some time?

Here is the code:

```
        $cleanQuery = str_replace(" ","+",$text);
        $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='.$cleanQuery;
        $scrape = file_get_contents($url);
```

$text is the text entered by the user while searching. But the problem is it works only for sometime, then it stops.

Working example: http://www.alleffort.com/tools/findurl.php

If you enter some text in the textarea, then on submits it should retrieve all the related information, but it is not working.

Comment: have you tried replacing `http` with `https` ???

Comment: @NishantSolanki yes, but no effect :(

Comment: Dont ever scrape google. They detect and stop this. And bring the odd lawsuit :-(

Comment: but i need to retrieve the information by scrapping, then what's the other way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably the string you are appending to the url:

```
 $cleanQuery = str_replace(" ","+",$text);
```

This does not prepare the string correctly for use in a query string, you would need to encode more characters than just the space.

Instead, you should use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$cleanQuery = urlencode($text);
```

Comment: still no results, here is the working example of my code.. http://www.alleffort.com/tools/findurl.php

Comment: @Insomania You are propably also running into limits imposed by Google itself.

Comment: @Insomania I would guess that Google limits the number of request you can make and there is nothing you can do about that. What is the exact problem now?

Comment: the problem is it shows limited results, when i enter a large number of keywords, it blocks for some time, may be for a day, then it starts working again, but i need to fix this issue, but don't know how to do this.. :(

Comment: @Insomania There is nothing you can do about that unless you have some licence agreement with Google that allows you to do that.

Comment: you mean any paid API?.. if yes then how can we get it?

Answer (score 0):

This code most probably help you for solving problem

```html
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```